# Can not delete module

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a little confused. It seems to me there is not way to delete a module in android studio. Am I crazy, or is true?

I can not find a way anywhere. If I manually delete folder from project, it just gets added again when I rebuild.

Answer (score 5):

In the Project Structure dialog, under Modules, you can select a module and click the **-** button to delete it, as in this screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of Project Structure dialog]

It will remove the module from your project, but you still need to manually delete it from the filesystem.

Note that if you're running older versions of Android Studio, there may be problems with deleting modules, and they will stubbornly reappear. That bug has been fixed, but I forget what version it was in; the latest version is 0.4.6, and it should be working well there.

Comment: Even in 0.4.6 We need to delete library module reference form main module's build.gradle file. Delete module from project Structure only deleting the reference from settings.gradle not from build.gradle file.After deleting reference from build.gradle file dependencies I am to delete the module by simple using Delete option from IDE,  no need to go to File System.

Comment: Using Android Studio 0.5.7 there is no longer a "delete" button in the Project Structure dialog. Is there a new way to remove a module?

Answer (score 4):

Go into the project settings.gradle and delete the module from that include statement, then right click and delete the module, and sync.